# Runtime annotation settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a mature ASP.NET WebForms project which provides services to lots of organisational clients.  Each organisation has lots of users but the Organisation itself has a lot of flexibility over user profile field settings.

I'm considering moving some or all of development to ASP.NET MVC.  The `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` appears to provide lots of benefits, however, in our application, the Organisation can control lots of details such as:

1. Which User Profile fields are actually used (the available fields are finite and can be part of the model but most Organisations won't use all of them.  I don't want these fields to be presented to the end user (based on which Organisation they belong to)
2. Wording: The Organisation (Administrator) can define the "display name" of certain fields (such as whether they want to call a StaffNumber field "Employee Number, Staff Number, ABC Code" etc. so it fits with what their staff are familiar with.  `DisplayAttribute` is a sealed class and so I cannot override it to provide a database lookup based on the logged in user's organisational settings.
3. ReadOnly: Some user profile fields can be edited by the end user, however some need to be read only based on a setting that the Organisation Administrator sets for their Organisation (in which case,  the values themselves are set through a Bulk Import/Refresh system)

All of the above in ASP.NET MVC can be controlled via Data Annotations but the values are hard coded into the attributes of the model.  Resource Files for item 1 above is no good we have over 2000 Organisations and new ones are created every week.

What I am looking for is a means to override attributes such as `DisplayAttribute`, etc. and allow the actual name to come from the data store.  I've had a look around but I can't seem to see anything here that fits the bill.

Can anyone point me as to whether such a technique is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `DataAnnotations`, consider using the [fluid API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean "Fluent API" rather than "Fluid API"?   I wouldn't know where to start adapting the metadata (at runtime) of classes using this technology.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant "fluent API"; I was typing a little too fast. You can override the `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method to do all the configuration of the entity mappings and properties. Just remember that this has to be done prior to connecting to the database so if you're trying to drive the configuration from the database it could be a bit trickier (possibly set up two separate DB contexts?).